# How to implement concurrency or context-switching in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, concurrency, context-switch

So I have this API endpoint called www.example.com/endpoint on which many devices post(I work in an IOT firm). We have implemented our whole backed in NodeJS and are stuck while scaling from 1 device to 'n' number of devices. The devices post their packets at this API endpoint, from where I execute  a complex bit of code(arnd 1000 lines) and save the state of the device in the database(mongoDB). Now the issue is. Whenever I receive a packet from device 1 and I am  executing it and in the middle I get a packet from device 2, NodeJS leaves the device 1 execution as it is and starts serving the packet 2 from device 2, I saw this when I put extensive console.log() statements
Now in an ideal world. I would want Node to save the context of my current progress with packet 1. then leave. and go on to save the packet 2 in a queue to be processed later. Once I am done with packet 1 I shall take up packet 2 and process it.
I know libraries like RabbitMQ and kue for storing it in queue and processing it later, **but how do I context switch from one execution to another?**
This is my way of thinking. There could be other solutions as well. Would like to hear your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: What does that complex bit of code do? Is it purely computational, or does it involve (lots of) I/O, like database/file/network interaction? Node can handle lots of concurrent I/O pretty well.

Comment: It involves lot of callbacks ...

Comment: Assuming that that means "lots of I/O", I think that something else may be causing your problems.

Comment: @robertklep somehow API doesn't come back to its original point. Maybe because it's stuck in addressing new IO and as the Node has a limited number of threads in the background.  A synchronous function, something like async.waterfall is required by the system with a queue like functionalities. I think I would have to write that. will take some time and effort.

Comment: Node will not "break" pending I/O requests. They might get queued up, but they won't break and Node won't lose track of them. I think it's a problem in your code, but without any code being posted in your question I can't say where you should start looking.

Comment: @robertklep can't post the code as it is proprietary but will definitely check out your viewpoint by extensive testing and come back with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** *How to implement concurrency or context-switching in NodeJS.*

**A:** Short answer: **Not** possible. Because Javascript is single threaded.

**Q:** *Now the issue is. Whenever I receive a packet from device 1 and I am executing it and in the middle I get a packet from device 2, NodeJS leaves the device 1 execution as it is and starts serving the packet 2 from device 2, I saw this when I put extensive console.log() statements*

**A:** As you might have already read in numerous places that `NodeJS` is based on an event-driven model that is non-blocking for I/O.

The reason why Node seems to have ditched `device1` midway to serve `device2` was because the code for `device1` has already been processed up till a point where it is just waiting on an `asynchronous function` to callback. E.g. performing a database write. So meantime while it is available, it went on to service `device2`

Similar case for `device2` - once it hits an `async` function where an event gets pushed into the event queue, pending for a return. `Node` might go back to `device1` if a response has come back. Or it could be other devices, `deviceN`.

We say NodeJS is non-blocking because the `node` process does not lock the entire web application down for a sole response. Instead it move on and pick the next event (essentially a block of code) from the queue to run it. Hence it is constantly busy, unless there is really nothing available on the event queue.

**Q:** I know libraries like RabbitMQ and kue for storing it in queue and processing it later, but how do I context switch from one execution to another?

**A:**
As said earlier. as of 2016 - it is still not possible for Javascript to do threading. NodeJS is **not** designed for heavy computation work, it should only be focused on serving requests therefore the code should preferably be light and non-blocking. Basically you will want to leave those heavy I/O duties like writing to file or databases or making HTTP requests (network) to other processes by wrapping the calls with async functions.

NodeJS is not a silver bullet technology. If your application is expected to do a lot of computational work on the event thread then `Node` is probably not a good choice of technology but it is not the end of the world - as you can fork your own child process for the heavy computational jobs.

**See:**
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

You might also want to consider alternative like `Java` which has `NIO` and `Threading` capabilities.